# How to get ISO-8859-1 encoded string?

Tags: javascript, character-encoding, iconv

I am working on pass authorization header to encoded text. Server expects ISO-8851-1 encoding format.

Here I used iconv and try to get encoded string and it gives a different encoded string . what can be the reason?

```
var str = this.username+':'+this.password;
var icBufeer = iconv.encode(str, 'ISO-8859-1');
var auth = btoa(icBufeer .toString());
headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic ' + auth );
```

Comment: What exactly does it give you…?

Comment: It is giving encoded string, but it is not look ISO-8859-1 encoded format. may be i am wrong in iconv calling. Is there any better way to get ISO-8859-1 encoded format in javascript?